# Исключение при обращении к серверу

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, http

При обращении к серверу из клиента выскакивает исключение `System.Net.WebException`.(В клиенте). Дополнительные сведения: Сервер нарушил протокол. `Section=ResponseStatusLine`. А при обращении из браузера всё работает нормально. Клиентская и серверная часть написаны на *C#*.

Код сервера:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Server
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress localAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAddress, 2200);

            listener.Start(1);

            string[] HtmlLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\SRV\index.html");            


            while (true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Сервер ожидает {0}", listener.LocalEndpoint);
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                HtmlLines[7] = "This Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
                //string Html = String.Join("<br>", HtmlLines);
                string Html = "HELLO";
                string Str = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\nContent-type: text\nContent-Length:" + Html.Length.ToString() + "\n\n" + Html;
                byte[] Buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Str);

                NetworkStream io = client.GetStream();

                Console.WriteLine("Принято соединение от {0}", client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);

                Console.WriteLine("Отправляем сообщение...");
                io.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);

                Console.WriteLine("Закрытие соединения");
                client.Close();


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Произошла ошибка {0}", e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Код клиента:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter URL: ");
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri(Console.ReadLine());

                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                    HttpWebResponse respone = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    Stream io = respone.GetResponseStream();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        Console.Write((char)io.ReadByte());
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем два раза `Content-type: text`?

Comment: Спасибо, поправил.

Comment: Может быть, нужен пробел после `Content-Length:`?

Comment: Ну и возможно нужно больше заголовков. Например, `Date:`